# Github pull requests and simulating a merge, before actual merge

Tags: python, github, github-api, pull-request, git-patch

What are the general steps that I need to follow to generate a local copy of the source (before it actually gets merged) as it would be if a pull request gets merged?

An example situation: suppose, User A forks repo_X (owned by User X) to repo_X_A, does a change to sources *src/brittle.c* and *libs/brittle-lib.c*, and raises a github pull request for the repo repo_X. Now, assuming am user X who would want to run some checks on the source before I merge it to repo_X, I want to generate the copies of these sources *brittle.c* and *brittle-lib.c* with changes (without actually merging the changes to repo_X). Can I do it programmatically?

Through GitHub APIs (esp the [pull req API](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests-files)), I can get the list of modified files for a given pull req. Now, what do I do to generate a local copy of the sources as they would be after applying the changes in pull request?

If am right, I should be getting the diffs in .patch format ([through API again](http://developer.github.com/v3/media/#commits-commit-comparison-and-pull-requests)), obtain the source from the repo/branch/tag, patch the diff onto it. Need pointers on how to achieve this part of applying the changes in a python program? Using python bindings for *nix patch utility?

Is this indeed the right way, or is there an easier/better/elegant way? Am trying with python-requests and github APIs.

Comment: Do you know how to do this from the command line with just Git? Is there a reason why you're trying to create a Python program to do this?

Comment: You mean the 'git diff' and 'patch src.c < change.diff' method? Am aware of that. Just that, I was trying to get it done through the python program which is written to analyze the source code; instead of getting these done via CLI.

Comment: I don't think any possible way could be more elegant than `git checkout user-a's-branch`.